# Batch file to schedule Windows Defender every time it starts

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file script to add Windows Defender to my schedule list, but not sure what parameter to use except `/ST 22:00` (which is specified time), but my aim is to make it work every time it starts (scans and updates), rather than specified time. Do any of you know how? Thanks.

My script:

```
@echo off

SchTasks /Create /SC WEEKLY /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT /TN Antivirus /TR "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe -Scan -SignatureUpdate" /ST 22:00
pause
```

Comment: I do not quite get the question. You want to create a schedule to start Windows Defender when Windows Defender starts? does not make sense.

Comment: Usually, Windows Defender or Microsoft Essentials put the shedule task in Windows when you installed them, but it's not always the case when you have hundreds of computers to take care off. My goal is to create a simpler .bat file to make the work done faster. To make sure it started, scans and updates itself. I can't figure out what parameter to put to make it do it everytime someone starts it, not just specified time. What to do when the task is deleted and you need to create it yourself?

Comment: @Tautvydas: It's not clear what you want. I understand it the same ways as the first comment already mentioned: `You want to create a schedule to start Windows Defender when Windows Defender starts? does not make sense.` Please be more accurate about when the Windows Defender should start. Don't simply write `to make it work every time it starts` or `to make it do it everytime someone starts it`. This doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: `/SC onStart` or `/SC onLogon`